# x86 Interrupt Table Modification

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, interrupt

I'm writing my own protected mode operating system and need to know how to modify the interrupt table so that certain ones (print string, etc.) are redirected to the command prompt application or other applications. How do I modify the table?

Comment: Any discussion of OS architecture and system calls is.. well, it's just a massive subject. 'I mean that it will place strings and stuff in a specified location that the command prompt can look for' - if it turns out to be remotely that easy, I will be surprised.  Typically, such a 'redirect to another app' would mean that the 'strings and stuff' would go into a OS-allocated struct/object and signalled to a thread in the other process.  It's very complex and can't be designed by blog because the mechanism/s used are architecture-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using interrupts for system calls is really not the "nice" way to actually implement them anymore. If you're targeting x64, then you should definitely look into `SYSCALL` and `SYSRET`, which enable very convenient (from the user's point of view) calling of kernel code, provided that you're willing to deal with some setup routines needed to use those two. If that isn't an option, consider mapping some of the kernel code into processes' virtual memory space. Google for `linux-gate.so.1` to read about an example implementation of that.

But, if you still want to implement syscalls via interrupts, then read on. Of course, you'll probably need to modify the interrupt table either way in order to actually interact with the hardware.

In the Protected Mode of x86, interrupts are placed in the IDT, which is short for an Interrupt Descriptor Table. That table can contain either a Task Gate Descriptor, an Interrupt Gate Descriptor, or a Trap Gate Descriptor. The table is indexed in a similar way to the Real Mode Interrupt Vector Table - e.g. the `n`-th entry of the table contains the descriptor that will be used to service the interrupt `n`. Interrupt and trap gates are really just pointers to the interrupt routine code with some extra data, while a task gate contains a Task State Segment Selector, which is a selector of the task that is supposed to handle that interrupt. In 64-bit mode, only interrupt/trap gates are supported due to the deprecation of hardware task handling.

I don't really see the point in simply rephrasing the Intel manual, which explains these issues very clearly, so I suggest you just [have a read](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325384.pdf) (though you should have those manuals by now). Interrupt handling is described in chapter 6 of that document.